# Get sheetname from current sheet in Loops in Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to write a python code that reads all xlsx files in current working directory and outputs them as CSV files.

A single Excel xlsx file contain multiple sheet, so I have to create one CSV file per sheet. The filename for CSV should be .csv

my code is:

```
import os
import openpyxl
import csv  

for excelFile in os.listdir('.'):
    if excelFile.endswith('.xlsx'):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excelFile)
        for sheet in wb:
            sheetname=sheet.title
            csvFileName = open(excelFile +"-"+ sheetname+ '.csv', 'w', newline='')
            csvFile = csv.writer(csvFileName)
            for rowNum in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
                rowData = []
                for colNum in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
                    cellData = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=colNum).value
                    rowData.append(cellData)
                csvFile.writerow(rowData)
            csvFileName.close()
```

It gives me what I want, but the only thing I don't understand is the output name is looks like: example.xlsx-sheet1.csv. However I don't want to .xlsx show up here, so what i want is the filename without .xlsx., therefore the result is example-sheet1.cvs.

So what change should I make for the current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening the new file just remove the extension from `excelFile`:

```
import os
import openpyxl
import csv  

for excelFile in os.listdir('.'):

    name, extension = os.path.splitext(excelFile)

    if extension == 'xlsx':
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excelFile)
        for sheet in wb:
            sheetname=sheet.title
            csvFileName = open('{}-{}.csv'.format(name, sheetname), 'w', newline='')
            csvFile = csv.writer(csvFileName)
            for rowNum in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
                rowData = []
                for colNum in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
                    cellData = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=colNum).value
                    rowData.append(cellData)
                csvFile.writerow(rowData)
            csvFileName.close()
```

On a different note, you should try and avoid naming variables in a mixedCase convention and stick to lower case and underscores. I suggest you go over the PEP8 guidelines for a better idea of the common naming conventions - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.